# Add Contacts into AddressBook without UI

Tags: iphone

Can anyone please provide me with a few lines of code i can use to add contacts into iphone without using the UI controls.There have been a few answers stating its simplicity but none has mentioned a few steps to do.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Read the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html).
2. Get a reference to the address book: `ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();`.
3. Create a new person record: `ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();`.
4. Set the person's properties, e.g.: `ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("Katie"), &anError);`.
5. Add the record to the address book: `ABAddressBookAddRecord()`.
6. Save the changes: `ABAddressBookSave()`.
7. `CFRelease(addressBook);`.

Answer (score 1):

this helper from Erica Sadun will come in very handy

https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper